# How to avoid having a mixture of GET request and socket.io messages?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, socket.io

I'm tying to learn how to develop a real-time website with node.js, angular.js and socket.io and got something up and running relatively quickly like this:

**html**

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
   <p> {{name}} = {{value}} </p>
</div>
```

**client-side js**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
var socket = io()

app.controller("myController", function($scope, $http) {

    $http.get("myData").then(function(response){
        $scope.name = response.data.name
        $scope.value= response.data.value
    });

    socket.on('myDataSocketMsg', function(message){
        $scope.$apply(function(){
            $scope.name = message.name
            $scope.value = message.value
        });
    });
});
```

**server-side js**

```
// data from text file
function getDataFromFile() {
   data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('dataFile'));
   io.socket.emit("myDataSocketMsg",data)
};
fs.watchFile('dataFile', function(curr, prev) {
    getDataFromFile();
});
getDataFromFile();

// router
app.get('/myData', function(req, res){
    res.json(data);
});
```

As you can see, it uses the get request to populate the html as the page first loads, and uses the socket message to push update to the view when the json in the server changes. If I don't use the get request in the client then the html does not contain any data when the page first loads. The socket still updates it when I update the data file of course.

It feels clunky to me as I have to do things twice on both the server and the client: The server has to make the json available via the router and send it with a socket message. And the client has to deal with parsing the data to $scope.name and $scope.value for the socket and the get request.

Is there a better/more elegant/best practice way to achieve this? Is there a way to get rid of the need for a get request to initially populate the html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the connection event on the server side to send the initial data.

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('dataFile'));
  io.socket.emit("myDataSocketMsg",data)
});
```